# iPhone - Reuse, Share code between projects

Tags: iphone, share, reusability

I've found a really good tutorial on "*Easy, Modular Code Sharing Across iPhone Apps: Static Libraries and Cross-Project References*"

Now I need to understand if my approach can work.

Suppose I have my "main" project with all the assets I need (View Controllers, Delegates, etc.).

Now I create a new project and simply add a reference to every file I need from the first project; of course I DON'T select the "copy if needed" option.

In this way do I build a new project with all the assets from my main project?

If I change the code in the main project, this change will be reflected to all the referencig projects?

Is this an easier way to share code between projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I keep all my code under version control, the way I do it is to have modular code as Git repositories. That way, to add common code, or chunks of functionality to my project I just need to add these as submodules.

The advantages of this are:

- Common code is kept in one place, versioned and backed up.
- Having small repositories for code that does just one thing encourages writing modular code with minimal dependencies.
- Submodules are added to a repository at a particular revision. So, if you change your common codebase, these changes are not automatically applied to the clones - you have to explicitly pull in changes. That way, if you accidentally change something that could break one of your projects, it won't appear suddenly.
- If you set up your submodules properly, you can make changes to the common code from within one of your projects that can be pushed to all other repositories. That way you can work locally.
- Your entire project is in a repository, without references to other projects, so you can move them, save them, archive and restore them without worrying about where the references point to.

Comment: This sounds really good! Can you tell me how to configure XCode to support this management system? Is it easy to do? Do I need some kind of external software to manage this? Thanks.